# Why does Phaser scale a game according to the DPI settings of Windows?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am developing a simple game in HTML/JS/Phaser. The game I am creating is supposed to be using a resolution of 640x480. The final canvas on the website has a size of 800x600, which is exactly what my Windows DPI scaling is (+25%):

```
Width:  640*1.25=800
Hieght: 480*1.25=600
```

This is very counter-productive and I do not want to use this scaling.

How can I disable this feature in Phaser?

Comment: How are you getting/setting canvas size? CSS "pixels" are actually scaled based on your screen DPI. For instance, check here:
https://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/viewport

Comment: @Eric This appears to be the problem. Can I somehow prevent CSS pixels from being scaled?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting/setting your canvas size via Javascript, you can use `window.devicePixelRatio`. Divide all your sizes to get dimensions in "real" pixels.